# What are the rules for a valid dereferencing of a null pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, exception

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    bool isNull() { return this == nullptr; }
    bool isNullConst() const { return this == nullptr; }
};

bool isNull(X& x) { return &x == nullptr; }
bool isNullConst(const X& x) { return &x == nullptr; }

// always false or exception.
bool isNullCopy(X x) { return &x == nullptr; } 

int main()
{
    X* x = nullptr;
    std::cout << x->isNull() << '\n';
    std::cout << (*x).isNull() << '\n';
    std::cout << isNull(*x) << '\n';
    // std::cout << isNull2(*x) << '\n'; // exception.
}
```

Here, I know that `X::isNull()` is equivalent to `isNull(X&)` and that `X::isNullConst()` is equivalent to `isNullConst(const X&)`.

What I did not know is that it's normal to dereference a null pointer. I thought that any dereferencing for a null pointer would result in an exception.

After playing with pointers for a bit, I concluded that dereferencing a null pointer itself is not the problem, the problem is trying to read or write to the address pointed to by the null pointer.

And since the functions are in a well known location in memory, dereferencing a null pointer to a class and calling one of its functions will just result in calling the function with the null object as the first parameter.

That was new to me, but that's probably not the complete picture.

I thought at first that this was an OOP concept at first, thus it should work in java for example, but it didn't work here and caused an exception (which makes me think why it doesn't work in java?...):

```
class X
{
    boolean isNull() { return this == null; }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = null;
        System.out.println(x.isNull());
    }
}
```

So, clearly this is something related to C++ and not OOP in general.

What are all of the situations under which dereferencing a null pointer will be valid and won't cause exceptions?

Is there something else other than pointers of structs and classes that can be dereferenced successfully even if they're null pointers?

Also, why is calling a function of a null pointer without accessing its fields raises an exception in other languages like java?

One case where dereferencing a null pointer makes sense is in Red-Black trees for example. Null pointers are considered to be black.

```
#define RED true
#define BLACK false;

struct Node
{
    bool color;
    
    bool isRed()
    {
        return this != nullptr && this->color == RED;
    }
};

bool isRed(Node* node)
{
    return node != nullptr && node->color == RED;
}
```

Here, I believe it makes more sense to include the function in the `Node` class itself since it's related to it. It's not very convenient to include all of the logic related to the node inside it except for the one that checks for it being null.

Comment: First, Java and C++ are two separate languages. Second C++ has no checks for illegal pointer access.  Third, C++ has something that doesn't exist in Java -- undefined behavior.

Comment: In java a `null` object does not have any methods

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie afaik it exists in any language. Java just tries its best to hide it while C++ compilers try their best to make use of it

Comment: Aren't these "undefined behavior" scenarios in Java, for the most part, bugs in the JVM, and not actually language related issues?

Comment: fwiw, your edit adds something completely new. It could almost be a seperate question, however the answer is: `this` is never `NULL`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually I am not sure, for me Java is just a tool, I dont know much about how it actually works ;) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153843/undefined-behaviour-in-java

Comment: In my experience, if for example there was actual Java code that manipulated a null reference and got away with it without crashing in some runs of the app, it would be considered a bug and the maintainers of the JVM would need to address the problem.  It doesn't work that way in C++ -- you dereference a null pointer, anything can happen.

Comment: Dereferencing a **NULL** pointer is like writing a letter with the address "Asteroid av. 42, Planet Mars" and expecting the mailman to meet the people living there (they don't exist) and give them the letter.

Comment: @LucasCharbonnier or rather you give the letter to a mailman who lives at that adrees, but nobody does live at that adress ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes that's more accurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the rules for a valid dereferencing of a null pointer [in C++]?

C++ standard is actually somewhat non-specific about whether indirecting through a null pointer is valid by itself or not. It is not disallowed explicitly. The standard used to use "dereferencing the null pointer" as an example of undefined behaviour, but this example has since been removed.

There is an active core language issue [CWG-232](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue232) titled *"Is indirection through a null pointer undefined behavior?"* where this is discussed. It has a proposed change of wording to explicitly allow indirection through a null pointer, and even to allow "empty" references in the language. The issue was created 20 years ago, has last been updated 15 years ago, when the proposed wording was found insufficient.

---

Here are a few examples:

```
X* ptr = nullptr;

*ptr;
```

Above, the result of the indirection is discarded. This is a case where standard is not explicit about its validity one way or another. The proposed wording would have allowed this explicitly. This is also a fairly pointless operation.

```
X& x = *ptr;
X* ptr2 = &x; // ptr2 == nullptr?
```

Above, the result of indirection through null is bound to an lvalue. This is explicitly undefined behaviour now, but the proposed wording would have allowed this.

```
ptr->member_function();
```

Above, the result of indirection goes through lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. This has undefined behaviour regardless of what the function does, and would remain undefined in the proposed resolution of CWG-232. Same applies to all of your examples.

One consequence of this is that `return this == nullptr;` can be optimised to `return false;` because `this` can never be null in a well defined program.

Comment: Is the word "non-specific" in your answer same as "unspecified behavior" in standard?

Answer (score 5):

> I thought that any dereferencing for a null pointer would result in an exception.

No. Dereferencing a null pointer is [undefinded behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in C++.

C++ is not Java. C++ does have exceptions, but they are only for exceptional casses, not used all over the place (as in Java). You are supposed to know that dereferencing a null pointer is not allowed, and a compiler assumes that it never happens in correct code. If it still happens your code is invalid.

Read about undefined behavior. It is essential to know about it when you want to do anything serious in C++.

> What are the rules for a valid dereferencing of a null pointer?

The rule is: You shall not do it. When you do it your code is ill-formed no diagnostics required. This is a different way to say: Your code has undefined behavior. The compiler is not reuqired to issue an error or warning and when you ask a compiler to compile your wrong code the result can be anything.

Comment: writing this while trying to hunt down some UB :/

Comment: I've updated the question and included an example in which dereferencing a null pointer makes sense.

Comment: @StackExchange123 I saw the example, but frankly, it doesn't make sense

Comment: @StackExchange123 consider that if `x == nullptr;` then `x->isRed()` is already invalid, it isnt even entering the method

Comment: Does it make sense to put all the logic in the class except for this function? Also,I believe that functions are in a well known location in memory, why calling x->isRed() would cause a problem? does calling the functions has something to do with the pointer? Accessing a field for example adds an offset to the pointer and then accesses it and that should not work, but functions? what do they have to do with the pointer?

Comment: @StackExchange123 "why calling x->isRed() would cause a problem?" because it is not allowed. Period. It may appear to work in some circumstances, thats what UB is: Anything can happen, including it appears to be fine, but it isnt.

Comment: @StackExchange123 "what do they have to do with the pointer?" Everything?!? You need an object to call a (non-static) method, if you have no object you can't call the method

Comment: Well, probably either you've misunderstood my question or that I have a misconception. I believe that to call a function of a class, all I need is knowing the type of the object (to call the function defined its class) and the address of the object (to pass it to the function). So, according to what I've just said, in the first code snippet in the original question, `X::isNull` is completely equivalent to `isNull` that is defined outside `X`. What I meant by "what do they have to do with the pointer?" is that they don't need the pointer

Comment: to know the location of anything, the pointer is just passed as a parameter, as opposed to trying to access a field of the object which would require the pointer itself to be able to address the field. For the function to be able to get called successfully, all it needs is the type of the object (which is known to be X) and its address (which is null). Just knowing these two is enough for calling the function. I believe it makes sense to make it normal to be able to dereference a null pointer and call a function on it,but as you've said, if the standard says so, there is nothing to do about it

Comment: @StackExchange123 what you are talking about is mostly implementation details. Thats not how C++ works. Calling a function on a null-pointer is not possible in C++. No arguing will change anything about that

Comment: @StackExchange123 [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/51z9Tb).  The compiler, once it sees that you're using a null pointer, can produce code that is not expected.  For example, the compiler may assume that `this` can never be `null`, so the comparison returns `false`, not `true`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java your object declarations are references. So you can deliver a null reference to a method and it won't harm since the method can check if the reference points to a null object.

But calling a method onto a null reference won't work because the method is called upon the object behind the reference. Since it is null, the method can't be called onto any object so a NullpointerException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing a nullptr in C++ is an undefined behaviour, so technically *anything* can happen when you try to dereference a nullptr (and I mean: ***anything*** :)).